# Пользователи Онлайн на сайте

Tags: php, mysql

Заморочился проверкой пользователей онлайн на сайте. Пока накидал простенький код. Суть такова: при обновлении страницы проверяется есть ли запись с юзером в БД, если её нет, то добавляем, если есть, то обновляем время. Всё бы хорошо, но почему то не обновляется время уже у существующего пользователя. В чем моет быть проблема?

```
    function onLineUsers($UserId){
    $time = time();
    $sql_update = mysql_query("DELETE FROM user_online WHERE unix+300 < ".$time);

    $query_online = mysql_query("SELECT iduser FROM user_online WHERE iduser = '$UserId'");
    $result_online = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_online);

    if(empty($result_online)){
        $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_online (ip,iduser,unix) VALUES ('$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]', '$UserId', '$time')");
    }
    else{
        $sql_insert = mysql_query("UPDATE user_online SET unix = '$time' WHERE iduser = '$UserId')");
    }   
}
$online = onLineUsers($UserId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Храните информацию об **online** в таблице с информацией пользователя.

Два поля `is_online` и `udate`.

`is_online` изменяем когда человек авторизовался или покинул сайт (/logout).

Далее на каждой странице обновляем поле `udate = time()`.

Создавать отдельные таблицы не нужно.

Comment: всё конечно хорошо, но нужно решение конкретно этой проблемы